# xCode Active Configuration: Release, Distribution

Tags: iphone, xcode

In xCode 3.2.3 (haven't updated to 4.1 yet) under Active Configurations I have: Debug, Release, Distribution. When I select Release, I always get 'Base SDK Missing' and when I do a 'Build and Archive' and try to 'Validate Application', I get a Code Sign Error.

When I select 'Distribution' the 'Validate Application' succeeds.

I have confirmed that I am using a valid Distribution Provisioning Profile.

So, how can I get my 'Release' setting to work (ie. eliminate the Validate Application error of not code signing properly) and what would happen if I sent the 'Distribution' build to iTunes and it was accepted on the App Store?

Thank for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the Base SDK option under the release configuration in your target build properties.  It probably needs to be updated to an SDK you have available.

Answer (score 0):

Interestingly, there is a difference between "right clicking" on the project name, editing the  SDK and clicking on "Project" -> "Etid Active ...". Try the second one and see if it helps.

Comment: I didn't know there was a difference, thanks. I just neglected to change a Release setting like Ben mentioned.